# AWS Athena not being recognized in Boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-athena

I am trying to use AWS Athena from both the CLI and through boto3 but for some reason it is not being recognized. I have upgraded to the newest version of boto3

```
boto3.__version__
>>'1.4.4'

aws --version
>>aws-cli/1.11.56 Python/3.6.0 Darwin/15.6.0 botocore/1.5.19
```

When I go to do `client = boto3.client('athena')` I am greeted with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 83, in client
    return _get_default_session().client(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 263, in client
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 836, in create_client
    client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 63, in create_client
    service_model = self._load_service_model(service_name, api_version)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 93, in _load_service_model
    api_version=api_version)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/loaders.py", line 132, in _wrapper
    data = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/loaders.py", line 378, in load_service_model
    known_service_names=', '.join(sorted(known_services)))
botocore.exceptions.UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'athena'. Valid service names are: acm, apigateway, application-autoscaling, appstream, autoscaling, batch, budgets, clouddirectory, cloudformation, cloudfront, cloudhsm, cloudsearch, cloudsearchdomain, cloudtrail, cloudwatch, codebuild, codecommit, codedeploy, codepipeline, cognito-identity, cognito-idp, cognito-sync, config, cur, datapipeline, devicefarm, directconnect, discovery, dms, ds, dynamodb, dynamodbstreams, ec2, ecr, ecs, efs, elasticache, elasticbeanstalk, elastictranscoder, elb, elbv2, emr, es, events, firehose, gamelift, glacier, health, iam, importexport, inspector, iot, iot-data, kinesis, kinesisanalytics, kms, lambda, lex-runtime, lightsail, logs, machinelearning, marketplacecommerceanalytics, meteringmarketplace, mturk, opsworks, opsworkscm, organizations, pinpoint, polly, rds, redshift, rekognition, route53, route53domains, s3, sdb, servicecatalog, ses, shield, sms, snowball, sns, sqs, ssm, stepfunctions, storagegateway, sts, support, swf, waf, waf-regional, workspaces, xray
```

Same thing for the CLI, when I do `aws athena help` I get an invalid option. Any idea why this is happening? I am trying to automate a task as opposed to sitting in the GUI repeatedly entering queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem seems to be related to your version of botocore.

I have botocore version 1.5.55 and athena works fine for me.

I set up a virtualenv with your version of botocore (1.5.19) and I was able to replicate your issue.

You should just upgrade your botocore version:

```
pip install --upgrade botocore
```

Edit: According to [this github issue](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/909) support for Athena was included in v1.5.52